# Where should I ask for help with FAMIlab/3d printing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm a little intimidated, and I'm not sure which StackExchange fits my needs as a complete beginner. I will likely be using Blender for the modeling.

I'm looking for "best practices" before a simple sort of figurine printing, I suppose?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/):

> Blender Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people who
>   use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

However, I suspect any site where you seek a list of best practices will be closed as too broad and/or too likely to attract opinions.